# Get text value from Text component

Tags: react-native

I would like to be able to retrieve the content of a Text component in a TouchableHighLight component with the prop onPress . However, I can't do it.

How should I do that ?

```
<TouchableHighlight style={styles.quickReply} onPress={this.onPress}>
  <Text>Yes</Text>
</TouchableHighlight>
```

thank you in advance

Comment: Your question is bit confusing. I can't imagine a situation this code could fit. You're hardcoding the content of Text, so you're already managing it. Same case if your Text is reflecting a state field. Maybe your intention was to use TextInput...? Please, try to explain better your situation

Comment: Ok, my goal is to create quick replies in a chat (a bit like Facebook Messenger bots)

So I have predefined answers, and the user has to click on one of them.
And depending on the answer he clicked on, I'll display it in the chat, but first I need to be able to retrieve the content of the pressed text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's face it with an example: you're handling your quick replies in an array.

```
  state = {
    quickReplies: ['Reply 1', 'Reply 2', 'Reply 3', 'Reply 4'],
  };
```

You can render them like:

```
{this.state.quickReplies.map(reply => 
  <TouchableHighlight style={styles.quickReply} onPress={()=>this.onPress(reply)}>
    <Text>{reply}</Text>
  </TouchableHighlight>
)}
```

where `onPress` function could be:

```
  onPress = (reply) => {
    console.log(reply);
  }
```

Also note that `<Text>` from *react-native* accept an `onPress` prop too. You can easily use it without wrapping each element in a `<TouchableHighlight>`

Answer (score 2):

As you already know the value of the text, as you have set it, you should probably just pass it to your `onPress` function.

That means that you could do something like:

```
onPress = (text) => () => {
  console.log(text);
  // do all the things that should happen when the text is pressed
}
```

Then in your `TouchableHighlight` pass the value. This value may be from state or hardcoded as you did above.

```
<TouchableHighlight style={styles.quickReply} onPress={this.onPress('Yes')}>
  <Text>Yes</Text>
</TouchableHighlight>
```

Comment: I'm sorry if I wrote an answer after you posted yours, which is correct under all the aspects, but I wanted to be sure that @NoName could understand the relation which can exist between a component state and what it renders. Upvoted anyway.

Comment: @Milore it's ok. Thank you for your comment.  We are all here because we want to help others. It's good to see different ways of doing things.

Comment: @Milore Thanks a lot for your answers and explanations, I understood the 2 solutions to solve the problem ;)

Comment: @NoName if they were helpful, consider to accept one of the answers, to make this page more readable and the site tidier. Thanks.